# Hubspot custom modules and bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, hubspot

Hubspot adds wrappers around its custom modules. I desperately want to find a way to make this code work for Bootstrap carousels. Any ideas how can I let the carousel plugin know to target my item class inside this added Hubspot span and div wrappers?

```
<div class="carousel-inner">        

    <!-- this is added by Hubspot wraps all items -->
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_carousel_items" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget_container" data-hs-cos-type="widget_container">

        <!-- this div is added by Hubspot on each item -->
        <div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1462360389044" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget">

             <!-- finally, we have the carousel items here -->
             <div class="item">
                 <div class="hero" style="height: 765px; min-height: 300px; background-image: url(image.jpg);"></div><!-- end hero-->
                 <div class="container carousel-caption">Test hero</div>
             </div><!-- carousel item -->

        </div>   <!-- added Hubspot div around each item div -->

    </span>  <!-- added Hubspot span -->      

</div>  <!-- carousel-inner div -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is to remove the "item"  from the custom module.  Instead wrap each custom module in it with jquery.  For example give your column that contains the modules the class "bootstrap-flex".  Then add this:

```
$('.bootstrap-flex > span').wrapInner("<div class='carousel-inner'></div>");
$('.carousel-inner .hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget').each(function() {
$(this).wrap("<div class='item'></div>");
});
```